# Speed difference of dynamic and classical multi-dimentional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Are the usages (not creations) speed of dynamic and classical multi-dimensional arrays different in terms of speed?

I mean, for example, when I try to access all values in a three-dimensional array with the help of loops, Is there any speed difference between the arrays which created as dynamic and  classical methods.

When I say "*dynamic three-dimensional array*", I mean **matris_cos[kuanta][d][angle_scale]** is created like this.

```
matris_cos = new float**[kuanta];
for (int i = 0; i < kuanta; ++i) {
  matris_cos[i] = new float*[d];

  for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
    matris_cos[i][j] = new float[angle_scale];
}
```

When I say "*classical three-dimensional array*", I mean **matris_cos[kuanta][d][angle_scale]** is simply created like this.

```
float matris_cos[kuanta][d][angle_scale];
```

But please attention, I don't ask the creation speed of these arrays. I want to access the values of these arrays via some loops. Is there any speed difference when I try to access the values.

Comment: Create two programs, one with each method, and benchmark them. I doubt you would find any difference though.

Comment: You need to have huge data to spot such difference. By the way multi dimensional arrays are generally stored in row-major or column major format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of pointers (to arrays of pointers) will require extra levels of indirection to access a random element, while a multi-dimensional array will require basic arithmetic (multiplication and pointer addition). On most modern platforms, indirection is likely to be slower unless you use cache-friendly access patterns. Also, all the elements of the multi-dimensional array will be contiguous, which could help caching if you iterate over the whole array.

Whether this difference is measurable or not is something you can only tell by measuring it.

If the extra indirection does prove to be a bottleneck, you could replace the array-of-pointers with a class to represent the multi-dimensional array with a flat array:

```
class array_3d {
    size_t d1,d2,d3;
    std::vector<float> flat;

public:
    array_3d(size_t d1, size_t d2, size_t d3) : 
        d1(d1), d2(d2), d3(d3), flat(d1*d2*d3) 
    {}

    float & operator()(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) {
        return flat[x*d2*d3 + y*d3 + z];
    }
    // and a similar const overload
};
```

I believe that the next C++ standard (due next year) will include dynamically sized arrays, so you should be able to use the multi-dimensional form in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to spot any difference between them in a typical application unless your arrays are pretty huge and you spend a lot of time reading/writing to them, but nonetheless, there is a difference.

```
float matris_cos[kuanta][d][angle_scale];
```

1) The memory for this multidimensional array will be contiguous. There will be less cache misses as a result.
2) The array will require space only for the floats themselves.

```
matris_cos = new float**[kuanta];
for (int i = 0; i < kuanta; ++i) {
    matris_cos[i] = new float*[d];

    for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
        matris_cos[i][j] = new float[angle_scale];
}
```

1) The memory for this multidimensional array is allocated in blocks and is thus much less likely to be contiguous. This may result in cache misses.
2) This method requires space for the pointers as well as the floats themselves.

Since there's indirection in the second case, you can expect a tiny speed difference when attempting to access or change values.

To recap:

- Second case uses more memory
- Second case involves indirection
- Second case does not have guaranteed cache locality.